# Mutually exclusive events reward

Tags: probability, expected-value

Say I have an unbiased coin and if I roll heads I get 40 pennies reward and If I roll tails I get 80 pennies. I believe the following is correct for the expected reward from one toss:

```
reward = p(heads)*40 + p(tails)*80
```

however is there a formal proof?

Comment: Apart from directly applying the definition of expectation, what would be needed?  BTW, since the definition applies to any probability distribution, you don't have to assume the coin is unbiased.

Comment: Also, I think your question title does not reflect your question

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for LOTUS - or the Law of the unconscious statistician:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician

Your Bernoulli random variable $X$ has two values, 1, if tails (with probability $p$), and 0 otherwise. You can find the expectation of the Bernoulli random variable in a standard way:

$\quad\quad X \sim Bernoulli(p) \\ \quad\quad E[X] = p * 1 + (1 - p) * 0$

Now, define a discrete function $f(x)$:

$ \quad\quad f(x) = \begin{cases}
      80, & \text{if}\ x=1 \\
      40, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}$

$f(X)$ is also a random variable (function of a random variable is random variable), which has 2 outcomes: 40 and 80. This is exactly what you need since $Y = f(X)$ is actually a random variable that denotes the amount of money you win from your bet. Now, using LOTUS:

$\quad\quad E[Y] = E[f(X)] = \sum_{i \in \{0, 1\}} f(i)P(X = i) = 80 * p + 40 * (1 - p)$

IF it is a fair coin with $p = 0.5$, you have:

$\quad\quad E[f(X)] = 80 * 0.5 + 40 * 0.5 = 60$

Q.E.D. that your solution was right